# Insert dependencies dynamically in View (Javascript and CSS Files)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Friends, I am willing to follow the rules of the W3C where it is recommended that javascript and CSS files should be in individual files and not within the page.

Good, following this rule, and not wanting to overload the master page, I would like to embed the dependencies dynamically. So how could I insert the libraries dynamically? I think the bigger problem is the Ajax requests.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sstatic.net/so/js/master.js?v=6523"></script>
```

I tried using the JavascriptResult, but he writes the content on the page, and do not run as "Stream."

**Any help is welcome. Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the problem, you want to add script files dynamically to the page.

You can try jQuery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function, that can parse for you the result in very intuitive way.